# JavaFX Treeview shows no items in SplitPane

Tags: java, javafx, treeview, scenebuilder

I try to implement an TreeView in my JavaFX App. But unfortenatly no items are showed, but i cannot find an issue. I search for some example and did it like them.

I put an TreeView Control to my FXML File in SceneBuilder and selected the ControllerClass which was generated and selected the Treeview field from this class as an id for the TreeView Control in SceneBuilder.

I checked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33549795/javafx-treeview-shows-no-items) where the error was assigning new instance of `TreeView` but this is not my problem since I am setting the root directly.

That's my Controller code:

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Label label;

    @FXML
    private TreeView<String> treeView;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
        TreeItem<String> root = new TreeItem<>("root");

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            TreeItem<String> child = new TreeItem<>("Children " + i);
            root.getChildren().add(child);
        }
        root.setExpanded(true);

        treeView.setRoot(root);// = new TreeView<String> (rootItem);  
        treeView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.SINGLE);
    }
}
```

My FXML code:

```
<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="800.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.29797979797979796" layoutX="134.0" layoutY="154.0" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="800.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
        <items>
          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0">
               <children>
                  <TreeView fx:id="treeView" layoutX="39.0" layoutY="61.0" prefHeight="598.0" prefWidth="235.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
        </items>
      </SplitPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: Your FXML file doesn't appear to specify the controller class. Are you setting the controller directly in code? Please post the code that loads and displays the FXML.